# How can I generate an Excel from a DataTable and send it by mail in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to generate an Excel from a DataTable and send it by mail using C#...I have tried using below code

```
                Workbook theWorkbook = new Workbook();
                theWorkbook.SetCurrentFormat(WorkbookFormat.Excel2007);
                Worksheet theWorkSheet = theWorkbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                int iRow = 0;
                int iColumn = 0;
                theWorkSheet.Rows[0].CellFormat.Font.Bold = ExcelDefaultableBoolean.True;

                //Titles
                foreach (DataColumn column in DataTable.Columns)
                {
                    theWorkSheet.Rows[iRow].Cells[iColumn].Value = column.ColumnName;
                    iColumn++;
                }

                //Values
                foreach (DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
                {
                    iColumn = 0;
                    iRow++;

                    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        theWorkSheet.Rows[iRow].Cells[iColumn].Value = item.ToString();
                        iColumn++;
                    }
                }
                System.IO.MemoryStream theStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                theWorkbook.Save(theStream);
                byte[] byteArr = theStream.ToArray();
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArr, true);
                stream1.Write(byteArr, 0, byteArr.Length);
                stream1.Position = 0;
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream1, "filename.xlsx"));
```

But I am getting error in line 2 and line 3

Error Msg: 'WorkBook' doesnot contain definition of 'SetCurrentFormat' and no accessible extension method 'SetCurrentFormat' expecting first argument of type WorkBook could be found ----in line 2

Error Msg: 'WorkBook' doesnot contain definition of 'WorkSheets' and no accessible extension method 'WorkSheets' expecting first argument of type WorkBook could be found ----in line 3

I have imported DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet in the page..is there any import i am missing out??

How do i fix this error...is there any other directive i am missing or any package?? Or any alternative code would be appreciable to create new workbook
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMQzg.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ768.jpg

Comment: Using the OpenXML SDK the property name for Worksheets is just `Sheets` You can find the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbook?view=openxml-2.8.1 However are you using this code isn't designed to be using the EPPlus nuget package?

Answer (score 0):

Use below type.

```
Excel.Workbook newWorkbook =this.Application.Workbooks.Add();
```

Comment: this keyword is throwing an error...anything else that i can replace with 'this' keyword??

Comment: this referencing the current class.

Comment: Or else follow below tutorial. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd6c67/how-to-create-excel-file-using-C-Sharp/